# Select using linq based on 2 conditions

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection. I want to select values that matches 2 conditions.

```
var a;
var b;
foreach(SomeObject so in collection)
{
    if(so.Value == something) 
    {
        a = so;
        // break if b is not null.
    }
    else if(so.Value == somethingElse) 
    {
        b = so;
        // break if a is not null
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the above using linq iterating over the collection only once? There will be only one value of something and one value of somethingElse, if we can use that fact.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written?

Comment: I have no code now, but I have updated the question with what I want to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In your example code above, the values of `a` and `b` will get set to the last object to meet their criteria. Is that OK?

Comment: You should really have a go at it first.  People aren't here to write your code for you, we're here to help you with code you can't get working.  This sounds kind of like a homework problem you just want the answer to.

Comment: What is the types of your collection?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin, I'm sorry you understood that way. But I'm not asking for code here, I'm just looking for pointers. What I meant was I have no linq queries, but something like what I have posted. And btw, this is not homework. thanks for your interest anyway!

Comment: @MattGreer, that is OK. It is assured that only one value will be present.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, assume it is queryable.

Answer (score 3):

This solution narrows the list down to two elements and then goes from there.  `Take(2)` is used so the collection only gets searched until the two values are found.

```
var matches = collection.Where(x => x.Value == something || x.Value == somethingElse)
                        .Take(2)
                        .ToList();
var a = matches.Single(x => x.Value == something);
var b = matches.Single(x => x.Value == somethingElse);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
var a = collection.OfType<YourCollectionElementType>().FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Equals(something));
var b = collection.OfType<YourCollectionElementType>().FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Equals(somethingelse));
```

Your collection should implement `IEnumerable` at least to be able to use this code.
It depends on what the type of your collection is. If it implements generic `IEnumerable<T>`, say it's `List<YourCollectionElementType>` or an array `YourCollectionElementType[]` then you don't need to use `OfType<T>`, i.e.

```
var a = collection.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Equals(something));
var b = collection.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Equals(somethingelse));
```

If your collection doesn't contain that value, `a` and/or `b` would get `null` values.

Actually you can read all these things in MSDN. LINQ is not that hard to learn, if you try
For example:

1. [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)
2. [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

**EDIT**

In your comment you're saying that *It is assured that only one value will be present*. Is it of great importance that you need two separate variables? You could get the present value just like this:

```
object thevalue = collection.FirstOrDefault(i => i == something || i == somethingelse);
```

**EDIT**

Actually, I'd leave your loop as it is, only having added a line like this:

```
SomeObject a;
SomeObject b;
foreach(SomeObject so in collection)
{
    if(so.Value == something)
        a = so;
    else if(so.Value == somethingElse)
        b = so;
    if(a!=null && b!=null)
        break;
}
```

And if only one of the values is expected, then

```
SomeObject a;
SomeObject b;
foreach(SomeObject so in collection)
{
    if(so.Value == something)
    {
        a = so;
        break;
    }
    else if(so.Value == somethingElse)
    {
        b = so;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: My question was - can you do this in 1 statement, i.e, iterate over the collection only once?

Comment: Only one value of each something and somethingElse

Comment: @Sam Then you can use answers by Jon Hanna or Risky Martin. I'd say they're what you need

Answer (score 2):

```
var relevant =
  from so in l where so.Value == something || so.Value == somethingElse
  group so by so.Value == something into grp
  select new {ForA = grp.Key, SO = grp.First()};
foreach(var bit in relevant)
  if(bit.ForA)
    a = bit.SO;
  else
    b = bit.SO;
```

It could gain you something against some sources, in that only two items are retrieved, though if against a collection in memory I'd stay with what you had, but adding a catch so that once you'd set both `a` and `b`, you stopped looping rather than kept needlessly examining the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
collection
    .Select(x => x.Value == something
        ? () => a = x
        : (x.Value == somethingElse
            ? () => b = x 
            : (Action)null))
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .ToArray()
    .ForEach(x => x());
```

I tested this code and it worked a treat.

If the collection is out on a database somewhere then I suggest this:

```
collection
    .Where(x => x.Value == something || x.Value == somethingElse)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(x => x.Value == something
        ? () => a = x
        : (x.Value == somethingElse
            ? () => b = x 
            : (Action)null))
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .ToArray()
    .ForEach(x => x());
```

Comment: We don't know there aren't 100,000 non-matching items.

Comment: That's not a triple-negative. That there isn't 100,000 items, which don't match, is not a thing that we know. Grabbing 100,000 items, mostly null and continually doing so after we've found matches, and then creating an array, certainly would be a problem.

Comment: @JonHanna - Why is it a problem? I just created a list of 1,000,000 objects which matched on nearly 4,000 of them and it took only 52 milliseconds.

Comment: In memory or a database? I'd rather get two items from a database than 100,000, when I want two.

Comment: @Jon It filters before calling ToArray(), so no null values will be stored in a collection at any point.  Regarding databases, I doubt that `Select` statement would work.

Comment: @RiskyMartin You are totally correct, it's the matching cases its excessive with. Well corrected.

Comment: @RiskyMartin - I've edited my answer to ensure that the `Select` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but I wouldn't recommend it.  It would be cleaner to have your loop as you already have it now.

If you really wanted to know how, you could do this:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
var items = new[]
{
    new SomeObject { Value = "foo" },
    new SomeObject { Value = "bar" },
    new SomeObject { Value = "baz" },
};

var something = "foo";
var somethingElse = "baz";
var result = items.Aggregate(
    Tuple.Create(default(SomeObject), default(SomeObject)),
    (acc, item) => Tuple.Create(
        item.Value == something     ? item : acc.Item1,
        item.Value == somethingElse ? item : acc.Item2
    )
);
// result.Item1 <- a == new SomeObject { Value = "foo" }
// result.Item2 <- b == new SomeObject { Value = "baz" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understand your question but assume `Something` and `SomethingElse` are value type and known before the run-time, you can do like below in one statement.

```
        var FindItems = new[]
        {
            new SomeObject { Value = "SomethingElse" }
        };

        var CollectionItems = new[]
        {
            new SomeObject { Value = "Something" },
            new SomeObject { Value = "SomethingElse" }
        };

        var qSomeObject = CollectionItems
                          .Where(c => FindItems.Any(x => c.Value == x.Value));
```